# In Java, how do I create a temp file only in memory to parse xml?

Tags: java, file-io

I'd like to read in an XML response and make a temp file in memory out of the xml.
Then, I'd like to read in the file to see if certain elements exist.
After this is done, I'd like to just get rid of the temp file.
I am familiar with making and reading files to/from the file system, is it possible to not write, and then read, from a file in memory only?

Comment: Do you really need an actual **file** in memory (like "on a tmpfs"), or would in-memory-streams be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you bother creating it as a "file" in memory? Just keep it as an XML representation (whether that's using JDOM, the W3C DOM API or whatever).

It will be a lot simpler to examine in *that* format than as a "file" in memory. After all, if you had the serialized form of it, as it would appear on disk, then in order to query it you'd basically have to parse it again anyway!

Comment: I'm calling getInputStream() on an HttpURLConnection, is it possible to just pass that around and do various operations on it?

Comment: @bmw0128: Depending on your XML API, you can probably parse directly from the stream to a DOM representation, which you can then query etc.

Comment: I was trying to use JAXB, but the response XML will be different based on if the response is an error or not. So, now I'm thinking of using some other way to read the xml, and I'm thinking I'll need to make one pass to check for the "good" response, and if no there, make another pass through the xml to ge the fault...that's why I think i need to have the xml in memory so i can make two passes through it, sound about right?

Comment: @bmw0128: If you read into an appropriate XML API to start with, you *may* be able to convert to JAXB objects directly. I'd certainly hope so, although my experience of JAXB has been far from positive. If you *really* want the raw format though, read it into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then you can create a `ByteArrayInputStream` wrapping the same underlying byte array, as per Mark's answer. I'd regard that as a last resort though - investigate the "parse once then transform if necessary" options first.

Answer (score 4):

Does it really need to be a file?  Typically that is abstacted away.

For example, if you are using a stream-based writer or reader, you can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` and wrap your streams/writers/readers around that.  It would be very seldom that you should need to mock a file itself; if you do you're probably not abstacting as much as you could in your design.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);
w.write(...);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Similarly, a `ByteBuffer` can wrap a File but also simply an array of bytes in memory.

It seems like you don't even need it serialized at all however, as Jon notes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for you to create a temp file just to check the certain elements exist. Most XML parsers allow you to read directly from some input stream. All you need is to convert your XML response string into an input stream, then feed it to some XML parser to perform your check:-

```
// converting string to input stream
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( myString.getBytes( charset ) );
```